# How to fix error " reading .m2\repository\junit\junit\4.8.2\junit-4.8.2.jar" and compile with Java 6?

Tags: java, maven

I tried following this guide (https://github.com/CaptainObvious0/NoCheatPlus/wiki/Compiling-NoCheatPlus) and ran into 3 errors, two of which being that I'm not compiling with Java 6 and another which seems to be related to Maven. Below is the error log and again with "-e". I'd appreciate any help that can be provided.

pastebin.com/z1hPJ47J

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Please include the relevant parts IN your question (as well formatted text, not images please).

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two problems here.  Here is the maven error :

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project ncpbuildbase: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
>   [ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\Mark.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.8.2\junit-4.8.2.jar; zip END header not found
>   [ERROR] error: Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
>   [ERROR] error: Target option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.

The other problem causing this error is in the pom file :

> ```
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>2.5.1</version>
>             <configuration>
>                 <source>1.6</source>
>                 <target>1.6</target>
>             </configuration>
> ```

The source target version is 1.6.  You need to change that to 1.7 and recompile.  That shouldn't introduce any new problems.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the Java 6/7 error. Any suggestions regarding the first error, "\junit-4.8.2.jar; zip END header not found?" I did try reinstalling Maven earlier but I suppose that I can try that again.

Comment: Delete the file in your local cache $HOME/.m2/repository ... and use checksum policy. you have been faced with network issues...

Comment: I thought the first error was related to the java 6/7 error...  Follow the advice above and delete the file from the repository.